# Alert("") isn't function correctly when called in HTML? Using isNan to validate float as well

Tags: javascript, alert

Forgive me if I'm being vague, this is my first post and I'm a novice JavaScript writer, literally started weeks ago.

I'm working on my site for school and for some reason the alert window isn't popping up even when it's called. I might be missing the obvious but it's 4 am and I've been doing homework for four hours and I just got an 8 hour shift five hours ago, I'd love to sleep.
Anyways, I'll post everything I have relating to the code and errors and will check when I wake up (probably 6-7 hours from now).
I am using Notepad++ and Chrome for this as well.
Also to clarify, everything works fine besides the error window not popping up. I believe the isNan that I have that checks the number is fine, but again I'm new to JavaScript so it might not be. **Those are my two biggest concerns, isNan and the alert window not popping up.**
**Also when I click the button to add together the two numbers** (it's a very simple program, user entered number plus 9.99 shipping variable) **it outputs the number in a second textbox. But the second textbox will return "Nan" if I enter "asdas" or letters, rather than put out the alert window.**

Editing this, I might as well throw the website up (it's my student site, shouldn't be worried about having it hacked, I hope).
It has all the updated data in it as well.
https://wheeloftimestory.000webhostapp.com/

I'd rather not post my huge index.html since there's a lot of  tags that haven't been moved to a .js file yet so it looks awful. If this isn't enough info I'll try to update it.

**This is parts of my index.html**

```
    <script src = "ft.js"></script>
<form id="inputform">
<input name="firstnum" type ="text" size="6"> $ <input name="btn1" type="text" size="6">
<input name="btn2" type="button" value = "Calculate Cost" onclick="addNum(firstnum.value); verifyNum()">
</form>
```

**Here's my js.cs file:**

```
function addNum(n1) 
{
    var num1 = parseFloat(n1);
    var shipping = 9.99;

    finalNum = num1 + shipping;

    inputform.btn1.value = finalNum.toFixed(2); //rounds the decimal place to 2!
}

function verifyNum(n1) {

    if (isNan(num1.value))
    {
        alert("Please make sure there's no alphabetical letters.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the piece of code where you call `verifyNum`?

Comment: In your verify function, why are you using `num1` instead of `n1`?

Comment: @nabn `<input name="btn2" type="button" value = "Calculate Cost" onclick="addNum(firstnum.value)">` That's the call line, I edited it, before it was "addnum(firstnum.value); verifyNum()" and I also tried having verifyNum(firstnum.value).

Comment: @KenH. I'm not sure, I watched a tutorial and it used firstnum (which is the name of the input name in the HTML) instead of n1 and it worked. I tried using n1 just now and it ended up breaking the code so I honestly don't know either.

Comment: @LukeSitler - right now, what you are passing to your `addNum` function is not defined.  I don't know if `this.firstnum` is going to get you anything sensible?  But it is currently passing an undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

I changed isNan to isNaN(n1), KenH was right. My problem is solved :) Thanks to everyone who commented.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect this change, and also I think that you should be calling the verify number function before you try to use it?  Check out my code snippet below and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First the following code onclick="addNum(firstnum.value)" needs to change

Change the code as :

```
function addNum(n1) 
{
    **verifyNum(n1);**
   //Call the verify function inside addNum, before parseFloat
    var num1 = parseFloat(n1);
    var shipping = 9.99;

    finalNum = num1 + shipping;

    inputform.btn1.value = finalNum.toFixed(2); //rounds the decimal place to 2!

}

function verifyNum(n1) {

    if (isNaN(n1))  // use the function arg here - isNaN spelling corrected
    {
        alert("Please make sure there's no alphabetical letters.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Change the function call for DOM element as :

```
 onclick="addNum(this.firstnum);"
 //There should be one entry point to an event.
```

Comment: `this.firstnum` will be undefined and so will `num1` and `num1.value`

Comment: I changed the code to exactly what you have, I called verifyNum(n1) in addNum and edited: onclick="addNum(this.firstnum);" but I still have no alert window popping up. I also tried using confirm(""); but that didn't work either. Not sure what to do at this point

Comment: There are a couple problems with this - for one, `isNaN` is misspelled.  Also, you should be using `isNaN(n1)` so that you are directly accessing the value (as long as you are passing the value directly to the function.)  Also, it seems that you should be calling that function before you attempt to use the number?

Comment: @KenH. Can you make that an answer? It actually worked, I can't believe it. That one "n" not being capitalized made a HUGE difference. The window popped up as well, thank you KenH. isNaN highlighted in purple when I entered it too. I suppose working for 13+ hours takes a toll on me. Thanks again!

Comment: I updated my information and code snippet in an answer below - see if it works for you, @LukeSitler

Answer (score 0):

A potential way to make this work would be to add an ID value to your input element, so that would look like this:

```js
function addNum(n1) {
  if (!verifyNum(n1)) {
    return false;
  }
  var num1 = parseFloat(n1);
  var shipping = 9.99;

  finalNum = num1 + shipping;

  document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = finalNum;
}

function verifyNum(n1) {

  if (isNaN(n1)) {
    alert("Please make sure there's no alphabetical letters.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input name="firstnum" id="inputAmount" size="6" type="text">
<input name="btn2" value="Calculate Cost" onclick="addNum(document.getElementById('inputAmount').value)" type="button">
<div><p id="outputDiv">output will be here</p></div>
```

I improved the code snippet to show how to access the value, test for `isNaN` and output the value. A simplified version of what you have.